# php SoapClient Parsing WSDL: Unknown required WSDL extension

Tags: php, web-services, soap, saprfc, sap-basis

Couple of years ago I have developed a PHP application that uses Web Services to communicate with a SAP system that my customer is using. I've already encountered this problem then, but there was a workaround - I have replaced the "ws_policy" in WSDL address with "standard" and everything was fine.

ie:
http://xxx/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/srvc_0026B987B6DA1EE3BED5427588133521/wsdl11/allinone/**ws_policy**/document?sap-client=220

turned to 
http://xxx/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/srvc_0026B987B6DA1EE3BED5427588133521/wsdl11/allinone/**standard**/document?sap-client=220

Unfortunately, my customer has upgraded SAP version, and now the links have such a form: http://xxx/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/flv_10002A111AD1/srvc_url/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/yyy/210/yyy/yyy?sap-client=210

I have no idea, how to by-pass the problem of SoapClient not supporting the

```
<wsp:UsingPolicy wsdl:required="true"/>
```

tag...

Perhaps any of you has?

Comment: check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805488/php-soapclient-unknown-required-wsdl-extension

Comment: thanks for your reply @Kstro21 . I have already tried both approaches proposed there. As I mentioned - as far as the WebService address could be changed - I was able to cope with it, but now I'm stuck. De-requiring the policy is not an option.